# How to change color of space in vim

Tags: vim, colors, vi

How can i change the space color in vim. 
Right now, the space is gray and the color of `.` is somewhat grayish, so it is hard to identify what is `.` and space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Vim usually does not highlight common text with a background color.
- If you have problems distinguishing punctuation, change / adapt your *colorscheme* and/or font.
- There is `:set list`, which emphasizes whitespace, tabs, etc. Temporarily enabling this helps with whitespace issues, but I would not recommend to keep this on all the time. It's not a proper fix of your problem.

To solve your highlighting problem:
You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to comment out `!hi SpecialKey ...` in your theme config file. It handles all the special keys as well as white spaces.